# How can I add the MVC 5 project template to VS 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have `Visual Studio 2012` and want to add the `MVC 5` template.

How can this be done or it is only available in VS 2013?

Comment: it is not officially released yet.

Comment: Any idea when it is going to be release (separately for VS 2012)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update your Visual studio, Here's the link

https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids

You can find more detail from below post.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Here the direct link, web platform is broken: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/7/2F7FA65F-E8BB-42A2-99A2-7F355225D30C/AspNetWebTools2013_1Setup.exe

Answer (score 7):

MVC 5/ Razor 3 support for VS 2012 has not shipped yet.  If you want to get started with it, you might want to just install VS 2013 express.  It will run side by side with VS 2012.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532

These are generally some VS2013 asp net features which one can install for vs 2012 (from Microsoft)

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade your MVC 4 application to MVC 5 as as given in [**here**](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc). See [**this link**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) also.