# How to create a new MVC 5 project using ASP.NET Identity in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have downloaded "Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012" and installed. 
Doing this has installed MVC 5. Now, when I create a new project, the project selection box is showing "ASP.NET MVC 5 empty project" as one of the option, which creates an empty project.

What I really want is to use ASP.NET Idenity, so when I select to create new MVC 5 project, it should ask me for type of authentication (like, Individual user, Organizational, No authentication, etc).

Any idea of what else I should be including the project to enable this?

Also, I tried to google about it, but there isn't much clear information.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Do visual studio update or manually setup the authentication in VS 2012

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC5 project template for Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160683/mvc5-project-template-for-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get your question right, but the type of authentication can be set when creating a new project. Just click the *Change Authentication* button when creating a new project

[image: Change Authentication]

Comment: I think what you have shown is in Visual Studio 2013. I am using Studio 2012.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I haven't used VS 2012 for a while, but I'm afraid that you have to set it up manually. [Here's an example](http://httpjunkie.com/2013/340/develop-mvc-5-with-asp-net-identity-in-visual-studio-2012/) how you can do it. The example upgrades a MVC 4 project to MVC 5 with Identity, but the steps should be nearly the same.