# Is it possible to use asp.net mvc 6 in Visual studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to run asp.net mvc6 in Visual studio 2013? If so how can I do it?

If not would it be possible to do it?

Comment: not possible yet. not unless an add in or update is released which includes MVC 6 for VS2013. Remember, VS2014 is CTP - a technology preview and nothing more than that.

Comment: MVC6 is open-source and cross platform (http://curah.microsoft.com/69203/aspnet-vnextmvc6) so is it comming with VS ????

Comment: @rjdmello Oh god I should hope so!

Comment: yes it is with VS2014

Comment: Not an answer but a tip. You can use the free VS Code IDE to develop MVC 6 web apps. For more details see http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1234/aspnet5-apps-using-visual-studio-code-vscode-yeoman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once MVC6 is released you should be able to run it, but it will most likely not be possible to get the project templates that will be available in VS 2015. [I have a good tutorial](http://httpjunkie.com/2013/340/develop-mvc-5-with-asp-net-identity-in-visual-studio-2012/) on getting a MVC5 project similar to what was available as a template in VS 2013 while starting from an MVC4 template in VS 2012. The time it took me to replicate this process once I had done it several times was still close to 30 mins each time I wanted to do it. It was also easier because there was not a fundamental change in the framework from VS2012 to VS2013.

[Stack O Question for doing this with MVC5 in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160683/mvc5-project-template-for-visual-studio-2012)

So will it be possible,.. maybe. Will it be productive and smooth? It can't be. It will probably be at best a hack, and I can only imageine the restrictions you will have because a lot of changes in the way things build in 2015 using the new compilation wouldn't be possible, there are breaking changes in the difference from ASP.NET 4.5 & ASP.NET 5 as well as MVC 5.2 and MVC 6.

In No Particular Order..

1. ASP.NET on OSX and Linux
2. View Components
3. AngularJS Templates
4. Project Compilation

These are huge changes. I have slightly changed my answer because I believe the question has been updated. My overall opinion is that it will not be as easy to build an MVC6 project in 2013 as it was to build a MVC5 project in Visual Studio 2012. There are huge changes in the framework and even more in the actual IDE that would just make it counter productive to not use some version of 2015.

Answer (score 2):

The Asp.Net MVC 6 has introduced following new features

```
No More Web Forms
No More Visual Basic
Tag Helpers
GruntJS, NPM, and Bower Support
Edit while running the solution like Classic ASP editing
ASP.NET Dependency Injection Framework
```

So if you see these features which can not be compatible with earlier version of VS like 2013 so you can not run the MVC 6 in VS 2013..

For details of new features check below website

[new features in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6](http://mvc4all.com/mvc/top-10-new-features-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6/) can't be compatible with VS 2013..may be some updates from MS would help in future..